# ASP.NET Model View Controller Application on DreamHost PS

Tags: c#, linux, dreamhost

I have an account with the excellent DreamHost web service. I also have a P.S. which means I should be able to modify essentially anything I want on the server. I'd like to create an ASP.NET MVC application, and I'd like to be able to run this from DH. The problem though is that DH provides Linux servers only.

Is this possible or is this an IIS only thing? I can use Apache, Lighttpd, or Nginx servers.

Thanks!

Billy3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of Mono should support ASP.NET MVC.

This should help you get started:
http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_ASP.NET

What distribution of Linux are you running?

Comment: I don't know what distro DreamHost uses. If I had to guess, I'd guess Debian.

Comment: if you have root access, installing the "xsp2" package would get you started